# Top logo linking to different page on same domain, bad design?

Tags: website-design, navigation, intuition

I have a situation with a company's homepage at somecompany.com and a different web application at the subdomain tracking.somecompany.com which provides a specific function for users (tracking packages). Both pages has the company's logo in the top left corner. Would it be unintuitive/bad ui design to make the company's logo at tracking.somecompany.com link to the homepage at somecompany.com?

I personally expect clicking the logo in the top corner to take me to the "start" of the current page, in this case taking me to tracking.somecompany.com and I would find it weird if I'm directed to a different page with no real relation to the original site other than belonging to the same company. However, I'm not sure if this is just me or if most users would expect this behaviour. Any input would be appreciated.

Let me know if I can clarify or improve the question somehow or provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking the company logo to go to the home/start page of the website we are on is considered to be well-established design pattern. It is not just your personal expectations but every user would expect this behaviour. Taking them to a different place will only cause confusion and lower credibility of the website.

Answer (score 1):

Logo linking to 'homepage' is an established interaction pattern.

If you were to change the linking depending on the page you are clicking from you would be conflicting with the UX heuristic principle of 'consistency and standards', which helps to reduce learning and confusion.